# Jinja 2 select item[n] from list

Tags: python, jinja2

i have a list

```
list_data = [("q", "w", "e", "r"), ("a", "s", "d", "f")]
```

in Python you can just do:

```
for item in list_data:
    print item[0]
```

and it'll print q and a

my code should look like this:

```
{% for item in data_list %}
<div class="row no-gutter">
<div class="col-25">{{ item[0] }}</div>
<div class="col-25">{{ item[3] }}</div>
<div class="col-25">{{ item[2] }}</div>
<div class="col-25">{{ item[1] }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

but i don't know how to actually get item[0]

Comment: What do you mean by "actually get `item[0]`"? Aren't you getting it in `{{ item[0] }}`?

Comment: no it does not get item[0], at the moment it's just empty

Comment: What does `{{ data_list }}` show?

Comment: `{{ data_list }}` also shows nothing

Comment: Seems like the problem is `list_data = data_list` in the python render_template, how can i update this part like every second??

Comment: What do you mean by every second? @falsetru's answer is correct then.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the code is passing `list_data` properly: The names used in the Python code and in the template code are different: `list_data` and `data_list`:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> t = jinja2.Template('''
... {% for item in data_list %}
... <div class="row no-gutter">
... <div class="col-25">{{ item[0] }}</div>
... <div class="col-25">{{ item[3] }}</div>
... <div class="col-25">{{ item[2] }}</div>
... <div class="col-25">{{ item[1] }}</div>
... </div>
... {% endfor %}''')
>>> list_data = [("q", "w", "e", "r"), ("a", "s", "d", "f")]
>>> print(t.render({'data_list': list_data}))  # <---


<div class="row no-gutter">
<div class="col-25">q</div>
<div class="col-25">r</div>
<div class="col-25">e</div>
<div class="col-25">w</div>
</div>

<div class="row no-gutter">
<div class="col-25">a</div>
<div class="col-25">f</div>
<div class="col-25">d</div>
<div class="col-25">s</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do i actually use this code and what do i have to change in the html file?

Comment: @Nico, I don't understand what you mean. Maybe this? `with open('/path/to/the-jinja2-template') as f: t = jinja2.Template(f.read())`